How do I validate props for a component within a component in React?
I have been going through my application and adding prop validations using SonarLint to validate my work and all has been fine so far. But I need to validate a component nested in the main component and can't figure out how to structure it properly.
My component:
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export const Parent1 = () => {
    ...

    const ChildOfParent1 = ({ data }) => {
        ...
    }
}

const Parent2 = ({ value, onFuction }) => {
    ...
}

and my PropTypes validation I've been doing:
Parent2.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.object,
    onFuction: PropTypes.func,
}

ChildOfParent1.PropTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.object,
} 

SonarLint doesn't seem to think of ChildOfParent1 as valid as the warnings about props not being validated in ChildOfParent1 still show
I tried doing the following:
Parent1.ChildOfParent1.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.object,
}

But then SonarLint says 'data' PropType is defined but prop is never used despite the warnings disappearing in the code.

You have to declare the propTypes of the child component inside the parent component. But it's even better not to create components inside other components.

Why are you making a nested component? This is very likely to cause you bugs by forcing unnecessary unmounts/remounts, which wipes out focus and state.

@NicholasTower I don't have a reason why. I wasn't aware this was bad practice since I haven't had any issues before with having functions declared inside others. Good to know, though.

There is no reason why you need to nest the component inside Parent1
You can still do this and still achieve what needs to be achieved

const ChildOfParent1 = ({ data }) => {
        ...
}

export const Parent1 = () => {
    ...
}

const Parent2 = ({ value, onFuction }) => {
    ...
}

This way you can do whatever you need to do with your PropTypes.
